# Angular Filter Always taking expresssion as 'and' | Not 'or'

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="healthparameters.companyidfilter">
<option></option>
</select>

<select ng-model="parameters.nameidfilter">
<option></option>
</select>

$scope.all_users = [
{
        "param0": "value",
        "param1": "value",
        "param2": "value",
        "param3": "value",
        "param4": "value",
        "param5": "value",
        "param6": "value",
        "param7": "value",
        "param8": "value",
        "param9": "value",
        "param10": "value",
        "param11": "value",
        "param12": "value",
        "param13": "value",
        "param14": "value",
        "param15": "value",
        "param16": "value",
        "param17": "value",
        "param18": "value",
        "param19": "value",
        "param20": "value",
        "param21": "value",
        "param22": "value",
        "param23": "value",
        "param24": "value",
        "param25": "value",
        "param26": "value",
        "param27": "value",
        "param28": "value",
        "param29": "value",
        "param30": "value"
},
{
      and so on.......
}
]
```

I need to filter the data based on parameters(param1, param2,...). Right now the code i written for filter the data like this

```
var filtered;   
filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.all_users, {param1 : $scope.parameters.companyidfilter,param2: $scope.parameters.nameidfilter,......})
```

The above code filters data perfectly, but the problem is:

the result will be like this:

param1 && param2 so it performs "and" operation between two objects.

my question is how will we do "or" operation between two objects and returns all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) you can also pass a function as filter, you can return true if the value should be included like so:

```
var filtered = $filter('filter')(
    $scope.all_users,
    function(value, index, array) {
        return value.param1 === $scope.parameters.companyidfilter || value.param2 === $scope.parameters.nameidfilter;
    }
);
```

Comment: i need filtered data to be assigned in "var filtered", can you pls explain that too

Comment: It should be with this code,  see `var filtered = $filter('filter')`

Comment: Thanks @Martjin Welker